# My first Python program! Anyone care to review it an help me improve?

Tags: python

I just wrote my first Python program and it works! It is a program that will rename subtitle files to their matching video files so that media players will pick up the subtitles (e.g. it will rename "The_Office_3x01.str" to "The.Office.S03E01.str" if a file named "The.Office.S03E01.avi" was present in the directory).

I'd love for someone to comment/criticize my code and help me improve my coding style and make it more Python-y. You can find the code at http://subtitle-renamer.googlecode.com/hg/renombrador.py

As I said, it is my very first program in Python, so feel free to comment on anything like:

- Style (indentation, variable names, conventions, etc.)
- Design
- Python features I should be using that I'm not
- My use of the libraries

Thanks!

Comment: This would have been better on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There is, however, no option for mere mortal users to migrate at this time.

Comment: This does belong on code review, but +1.

Comment: @dheerosaur: `post.replace('python-y', 'Pythonic')` would be more Pythonic.

Comment: I like your header. I always grade higher when I see a nicely formatted header.

Comment: I didn't know about the code review site. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I've nominated for reopen, so it can be moved to codereview.stackexchange.com (I assume closed questions cannot be moved?)

Comment: @codeape: Mere mortals can not move this to code review (that may change after if emerges from beta), so it would take a moderator and mods have great power: they can do what ever it takes to get it squared away. But I flagged for their attention in the first place, and they don't seem to have been interested. *::shrugs::*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) A hash-bang line only works if it is the first line in the file.

2) Function and variable names are usually underscore_separated rather than camelCase.

3) Docstrings usually use triple-quotes, even for single-line docstrings.

4) Your coding style is very functional-flavored, with many lambdas, maps, reduces, etc, and one instance of a four-line triply-nested list comprehension.  I find it difficult to understand that style, and would definitely unroll some of those.

5) As an example of the problem that (4) can cause, you have a few places where you evaluate the same expression more than once because of the list comprehension structure:

```
match = [regex.match(str) for regex in episodeRegExes if regex.match(str)]
```

and then

```
def getEpisodeTuple(iterable):
    episodeTuple = [episodeChunk(chunk)
        for chunk in iterable
        if episodeChunk(chunk)]
    if episodeTuple:
        assert len(episodeTuple) == 1
        return episodeTuple[0]
    else:
        return None
```

Notice that the list comprehension here evaluates episodeChunk(chunk) twice, and each of those performs the regex match twice, so in your successful case, you are matching your regex four times.

In this last code, (a) you've called a list a tuple, and (b) you build a list, then assert it only has one element, and return the element.  It would be simpler like this:

```
def getEpisodeTuple(iterable):
    for chunk in iterable:
        echunk = episodeChunk(chunk)
        if echunk:
            return echunk
```

6) Learn more about the standard library.  For example, this code:

```
def splitWithAny(string, delimiters):
    "Splits the string with any of the strings of delimiters"
    return reduce(
        lambda iterable, delim: reduce(
            lambda lst,chunk: lst + chunk.split(delim),
            iterable,
            []),
        delimiters,
        [string])

def splitName(fileName):
    "Splits the fileName into smaller and hopefully significant chunks"
    delimiters = [" ", ".", "_", "-"]
    return filter(None, splitWithAny(fileName, delimiters))
```

I think (I'm not sure, because of the reduce(lambda(reduce(lambda)))) stuff..) can be simplified to:

```
def splitName(fileName):
    return re.split("[ ._-]+", fileName)
```

Comment: I'd consider functional style a plus.

Comment: Tastes vary.  I think there are specific reasons (added in an edit here) that this style is not helping in this case.

Comment: I've gathered, perhaps from a skewed segment of the Python-using population, that heavily functional-style programming, even to a lesser degree than what's used here, is generally frowned upon in the Python community.  I think part of the rationale is that it often avoids giving names to routines, which makes the code less explicit and readable.

Answer (score 1):

if you check it against [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you'll find a number of style suggestions (there are automated pep8 checkers available).

also, you can use something like [pyLint](http://www.logilab.org/857) can be very helpful.  The quality of my Python code has improved a lot by using them :)  (I have both set up on hot-keys in my editor of choice, and find them very convenient to use regularly).

Answer (score 1):

Couple comments:

1. Agreed with Ned's remark on docstrings.
2. If you're using Regex in one place why not also use it to take care of the string splitting?
3. This is confusing:

> ```
> return [
>         (getEpisodeTuple(chunks),
>         [chunk for chunk in chunks if not episodeChunk(chunk)])
>         for chunks in [splitName(string) for string in stringiterable]]
> ```

as you're splitting the logic of the one liner into multiple parts but not in a clear way.  If you think separating them is the right thing to do, then really do separate them.  You're not stopping the inner lists from being generated by not breaking this up into multiple lines.  Remember, loooong one liners are just as difficult if not more to decipher than loooooong methods.

Look how much clarify can be added by transforming it into:

```
splitNames = [splitName(string) for string in stringiterable]
chunkChunks = lambda chunks: [chunk for chunk in chunks if not episodeChunk(chunk)]

return [(getEpisodeTuple(chunks),chunkChunks(chunks) for chunks in splitNames]
```

Answer (score 0):

- `#!/usr/bin/env python` should be at the first line
- Use [docstrings][1] for multiline comments, and function descriptions.
- Include a general description along with the code so we don't have to guess what it is for.
- Avoid one line functions, be more descriptive with the structure.